# Power query - Convert hours and minutes in text format to duration format

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I have a column that consists time data in hours and minutes, but it is in text format and I need to convert it to duration format in order to measure duration per month which I will use in my dashboard. Is there a syntax in M language?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these are hours and minutes, then do the following.

Add a column with text before delimiter:

[image]

Add a column with text after delimiter:

[image]

Change both to whole number type.

Add a column as follows:

```
#duration(0,[Text Before Delimiter],[Text After Delimiter],0)
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Add column, custom column with

```
=  #duration(0,Number.From(Text.Split([Time],":"){0}), Number.From(Text.Split([Time],":"){1}),0)
```

then change column type to duration

sample code:

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each #duration(0,Number.From(Text.Split([Time],":"){0}), Number.From(Text.Split([Time],":"){1}),0),type duration)
in #"Added Custom"
```